# Accordion Panel required fields validation issue

Tags: primefaces

I  am using accordion panel with three tabs each tab has required fields for form submission.I want to validate required fields when submit operation is performed. But the validation happens during the tab change and I don't want this functionality, so how to remove this and validate the whole form during form submit. Please give me some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You should set your `accordionPanel` not to be dynamically loaded : `dynamic="false"`